# How to add a first empty value to a dropdown field in a form that gets its data from MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am using the following code in a html form to select values from a database:

```
 <p><strong>PRIMERA OPCION</strong>:     
     <p>POR FAVOR, SELECCIONE UN ELEMENTO DE ENTRE LOS SIGUIENTES:
  <select name="opcion1_linea" id="opcion1_linea">
    <?php 
do {  
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_Recordset11['plato_seleccionado']?>" ><?php echo $row_Recordset11['nombre_plato']." ( + ".money_format('%i', $row_Recordset11['sobreprecio_opcion']).")" ?></option>
    <?php
} while ($row_Recordset11 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset11));
?>
  </select>
```

At this moment, the values are shown, but I want that the first option to be shown should be the text "No needed" and the value to be stored should be 0.
How could I implement my need?

Comment: Write this option before the do-while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add in a hard coded value?

```
<select name="opcion1_linea" id="opcion1_linea">
    <option value="0">Not Applicable</option>
        <?php do { ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<p><strong>PRIMERA OPCION</strong>:     
     <p>POR FAVOR, SELECCIONE UN ELEMENTO DE ENTRE LOS SIGUIENTES:
  <select name="opcion1_linea" id="opcion1_linea">
    <option value="0">No es necesario</option>
    <?php 
do {  
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_Recordset11['plato_seleccionado']?>" ><?php echo $row_Recordset11['nombre_plato']." ( + ".money_format('%i', $row_Recordset11['sobreprecio_opcion']).")" ?></option>
    <?php
} while ($row_Recordset11 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset11));
?>
  </select>
```

That do it for ya?